# Is it possible to reconstruct the universally measurable sets in X from the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)^{**}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I asked this at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424581/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-the-universally-measurable-sets-in-x-from-the-c) 12 days ago, without success, I hope people here could be interested in this question and could help me.

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. Consider the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)$ of continuous functions on $X$, its Banach dual space $C(X)^{*}=M(X)$ of measures, and the second Banach dual space $C(X)^{**}=M(X)^*$ (each star $*$ means the Banach dual space).

It is known (see the [book by G. Dales, F.K. Dashiell, Jr., A.T.-M. Lau, D. Strauss](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-32349-7)) that

> $C(X)^{**}$ has a natural structure of  $C^*$-algebra, generated from $C(X)$.

Let now $Y$ be another Hausdorff compact topological space. Recall that

- if $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are isomorphic as C*-algebras,
  $$
  C(X)\cong C(Y)
  $$
  then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces
  $$
  X\cong Y.
  $$

This allows to conclude that the topology of $X$ can be reconstructed from the C*-algebra $C(X)$.

If we replace $C(X)$ by $C(X)^{**}$, this regularity breaks (see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420205/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-the-compact-space-x-from-the-space-of-measures)):

- if $C(X)^{**}$ and $C(Y)^{**}$ are isomorphic as C*-algebras
  $$
  C(X)^{**}\cong C(Y)^{**},
  $$
  then $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily homeomorphic as topological spaces:
  $$
  X\ncong Y.
  $$

However, in this case there is also a natural bijective mapping
$$
\varphi:X\to Y,
$$
what follows from the fact that the elements of $X$ can be restored from $C(X)^{**}$ as isolated points of its spectrum ([H. G. Dales, A. T.-M. Lau, D. Strauss, Second duals of measure algebras, Corollary 4.2](https://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/id/eprint/55803/1/DissertatmeasurealgebraSUBMITTEDCHANGES.pdf)).

I have a suspicion that despite the fact that this mapping $\varphi:X\to Y$ is not necessarily a homeomorphism, it still preserves $\sigma$-algebras of [universally measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set) (a set $M\subseteq X$ is said to be *universally measurable* if it is measurable with respect to each measure $\mu\in C(X)^{*}$). Is that true?

So in one statement my question is the following:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact Hausdorff topological spaces such that their spaces $C(X)^{**}$ and $C(Y)^{**}$ are isomorphic as $C^*$-algebras,
> $$
> C(X)^{**}\cong C(Y)^{**},
> $$
> and let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be the corresponding natural bijection. Is it true that for each set $M\subseteq X$, $M$ is universally measurable in $X$ if and only if its image $\varphi(M)\subseteq Y$ is universally measurable in $Y$?